# CultureInfo and default selection value

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

My function:

```
 public void loadCultureList()
 {
        CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        ddlCulture.DataSource = cultures; //ddlCulture is dropdownlist id
        ddlCulture.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
        ddlCulture.DataValueField = "IetfLanguageTag";
        ddlCulture.DataBind();
  }
```

When I use this function to bind `dropdownlist` I get first item is `Arabic`.

[image: culture]

But I want first item must be `English`. Is there any tricks to achieve this result?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the corresponding culture in the `cultures` array and create a new array where English is the first item and all the others have "moved down" one position.

It's very easy with LINQ:

```
var english = new[] { cultures.Single(ci => ci.DisplayName == "English") };
cultures = english.Concat(cultures.Except(english)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .OrderBy(p => p.EnglishName == "English" ? 0 : 1)
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to be sure the list is ordered by english name you can use

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .OrderBy(p => p.EnglishName == "English" ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(p => p.EnglishName)
    .ToArray();
```